# Dependent Dropdown List with multiple Columns

Tags: google-sheets

So I want to have all my different types of Equipment in one table. There are different categories of equipment with different sub categories and prices per piece.

In the second table I want to do my project dependent Equipment List. So I chose a main category and the the dropdown lists change to the pieces in that category. I got to the point where the name changes, but I can't find a solution to also bring in the subcategory and price.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G6Y5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlxwp.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

The concept you describe is known as *multiple-level dependent dropdown lists*.

Single-level dependent dropdown lists can be implemented with spreadsheet formulas, but when multiple levels of dropdowns are required, the whole thing is usually simpler to implement with a script.

See my [dependentDropDownLists_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/119308387?msgid=119315115) script for one example. The script requires that the drop-downs are defined through a row-oriented table like the one in this [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kCfP1zDkKXoGMys6xAQRcl_TaVCoHPDbAOIJ8zzDaDA/edit#gid=1938055344).